# Rendering a backslash from react-intl message when building with Webpack 1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

**Summary**

> When I load my app using Webpack Dev Server, my messages show up fine:
>   `\`. However when I bundle the application to disk and server the
>   bundle via `nginx`, I see a duplication of my backslash: `\\`.

**Details**

I am using `react-intl`@2.2.3 (latest at this time) and `babel-plugin-react-intl`@2.3.1 (latest at this time.) My goal is to define a default message with a `\` character and render it in any way (`FormattedMessage`, `formatMessage`, etc)

I am bundling my app using Webpack / Babel. I have no Babel / react-intl specific config in my `webpack.config.js` file, however I do use `DefinePlugin` to set `process.env` to `'development'` or `'production'`

When I load my app using Webpack Dev Server, my messages show up fine: `\`. However when I bundle the application to disk and serve the bundle via `nginx`, I see a duplication of my backslash: `\\`. I have following instructions here: https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl/issues/13#issuecomment-151944191 with regard to using 4 `\` characters to show a final `\` character.

For what it is worth, I have tried using JSX strings, JS strings, using 1, 2, and 4 `\` characters, and any other silly combinations I could think of.

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Code samples**

An example of how I define messages

```
import { defineMessages } from 'react-intl'


export default defineMessages({
  message: {
    id: 'anyId',
    defaultMessage: '\\\\',
  },
})
```

An example of how I might render my messages

```
<FormattedMessage { ...messages.anyID } /></span>
```

Another example, which also does not work

```
<FormattedMessage id='anyId' defaultMessage='\\' />
```

Yet another failing example:

```
<FormattedMessage id='anyId' defaultMessage={ '\\\\' } />
```

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution after a year?

Comment: It's still broken, probably forever. Ember js even forked react-intl message formatter to fix it. One way to work around it is to use ╲ (\u2572) instead of a real backslash.

Comment: Or symbol ∖, \u2216

Answer (score 2):

Use the unicode character instead of the actual backslash. The backslash unicode is `\u005C`. So it would look like this to render one backslash:

```
    export default defineMessages({
        message: {
            id: 'anyId',
            defaultMessage: '\u005C',
        },
    })
```

or this if you wanted to render two backslashes in a row:

```
    export default defineMessages({
        message: {
            id: 'anyId',
            defaultMessage: '\u005C\u005C',
        },
    })
```

or this if you were just done with it ;)

```
    export default defineMessages({
        message: {
            id: 'anyId',
            defaultMessage: '¯\u005C_(ツ)_/¯',
        },
    })
```

the last code would render: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this after 4 years, but it might be helpful for someone

https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax/#quoting--escaping

So for your problem it would be `defaultMessage: "'\'"`

Hope it helps someone else :)